# Magento 1.9.2.4 missing category tabs

Tags: php, magento-1.9, dashboard

I am missing my tabs from the category from magento. There are only two shown as on the picture 
[image]

I found this answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/category-design-tab-disappeared and checked in the database to see if it shows the other categories. It does. Can anybody point me where can i start the search for this.

Thanks